# What are "first principles" calculations?

Tags: density-functional-theory, terminology

A newcomer to density functional theory calculations is exposed to jargon which sounds rather non-technical at first. For instance, 'charge density' is something that is actually a term in the formalism, whereas terms like 'first principles' seem adjectival. Please help me understand what they mean and their relevance as to why are they associated with the theory almost everywhere.

Answer (score 15):

First Principles mean starting directly at the level of established science and not making assumptions such as any empirical models or parameter fitting. 
With respect to DFT, EMF (Electromagnetic force) is a very strong force governing nucleus and electrons (referring to a single atom).
With that, atoms, molecules, macro molecules and materials are built up. Whatever happens in materials (be it physical deformation or its fundamental properties) comes from this basic interaction. 
The law that governs these small particles and their interaction is **Quantum Mechanics**. The calculation methods (DFT) based on QM **do not** use fitting parameters from experiments or assume anything. They are solely dependent on basic laws of physics (*not Newton's laws*).
Thus they are named as ***First Principle (ab initio) Methods***.
**Just to give an idea:** The only information these calculation methods need is the **Atomic Number** of the atoms involved.

Comment: Do not use any fitting parameters?.. What about [When do I use the lattice parameters obtained computationally vs experimentally?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2405/721)

Comment: The  calculation  methods are  based  on  quantum mechanics, therefore, do not use any  fitting  parameters from the experimental data as used in MD(Molecular Dynamics) and are based solely on the basic laws of physics.
You can refer https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Computational_Materials_Science.html?id=4eiVDQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: You still do need input data that would influence whether you're modeling e.g. 3O₂ or 2O₃ system. And that can actually rely on experimental parameters like bond lengths or whatever.

Comment: I think those parameters directly depend on the atomic number.

Comment: In the example system there is only one atomic number: 8, and there are 6 of these atoms. Their arrangement defines whether it's ozone or oxygen.

Comment: Oh okay, So what edit to the answer would you suggest?

Comment: I don't know, I wanted you to tell what exactly parameters are acceptable in ab initio calculations and what aren't. But rejecting _all_ parameters is obviously wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113915/discussion-between-saismaran-s-b-pes1201701189pes-and-ruslan).

Comment: @Ruslan I think you're confusing between (a) the input given to perform a calculation and (b) the theory/algorithm used to perform a calculation on the given input. The lattice parameters referred to in the question you linked is (a), the input for a calculation and in this answer, "no parameter fitting" refers to (b), i.e., the theory used for calculation. That is, the theory doesn't use empirical data to perform the computation on a given input.